# Verified multiline regex works in notepad++, but no results in python

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I'm a python noob, and I'm having a bit of trouble with regex results.  I've written out my regex and verified it works in notepad++. What must I consider when I'm transferring a regex from notepad++ to python?  I get the feeling that the \r\n within the regex is the trouble, but all I get is a "None" result for my printed results.  What is happening?  Thanks for the help!

```
#!python

import re
scmFile = open("scm.txt")
scmContent = scmFile.read()
nameRegex = re.compile(r"(899\*0)\r\n[ ]+(([a-z, A-Z-])+[ ]([a-z,A-Z-])+)", re.MULTILINE)
searchResults = nameRegex.search(scmContent)
#print(scmContent)
print(searchResults)
```

Comment: This site can generate Python code https://regex101.com/

Comment: Try removing `\r` from your pattern?

Comment: moogle, that totally worked!  I figured it'd be something that related to \r\n, but why is \r included in notepad++, but not in the python file?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Can you close this question, if it's solved?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest turning `\r` into an *optional* subpattern and optimize the Group 2 subpattern as follows:

```
nameRegex = re.compile(r"(899\*0)\r?\n[ ]+([a-z, A-Z-]+(?:[ ][a-z,A-Z-]+)?)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/crrZOs/1). **Note** that the commas inside `[...]` are meaningful, if you used them as range delimiters, consider removing the commas. I left the spaces inside `[ ]` only because it might be handy if you plan to use `re.VERBOSE` flag that will make all whitespace in the pattern (outside character classes) meaningless (used for formatting purposes only).

Note that `re.MULTILINE` flag is redundant because it only redefines the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors, and does not have any affect on the input string parsing.

**Pattern description**:

- `(899\*0)` - Group 1 capturing `899*0`
- `\r?\n` - an optional CR followed with LF
- `[ ]+` - 1+ regular spaces
- `([a-z, A-Z-]+(?:[ ][a-z,A-Z-]+)?)` - Group 2 capturing a sequence of:

  - `[a-z, A-Z-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `,`, space, `-`
  - `(?:[ ][a-z,A-Z-]+)?` - one or more occurrence of:

    - `[ ]`  - a space
    - `[a-z,A-Z-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `,` or `-`.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured it'd be something that related to \r\n, but why is \r included in notepad++, but not in the python file?

See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> Normally, files are opened in text mode, …
>
> In text mode, the default when reading is to convert platform-specific line endings (\n on Unix, \r\n on Windows) to just \n.